# Centering Images in Mobile Responsive View

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, center

I'm working on a website with `Bootstrap` and `FontAwesome` that includes clickable images and font-awesome elements that intersect. As a result, I came up with the following code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
  </head>
  <body>

    <style>
               
        .tr {
             border: none;
         }

         .ebp_container {
             /* What you need */
             position: relative;
             /* the code below is only for this example */
             width: 300px;
             /*background-color: yellow;*/
             margin: 10px;
             padding: 20px;
         }

     


         .ebp_video {
             /* What you need */
             position: relative;
             z-index: 2;
             /* the code below is only for this example */
             width: 80px;
             /* height: 100px;*/
             display: flex;
             align-items: center;
             justify-content: center;
             text-align: center;
             color: var(--eniac-blue);
             cursor: pointer;
             /*Background*/
             border-radius: 15px;



             /*Centering the immages*/
             display: block;
           margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
         }


             .ebp_video:hover {
                 /*    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);*/
                 opacity: 0.9
             }






         .ebp_pdf {
             /* What you need */
           
             position: absolute;
             top: 70px; /* change value to desired position */
             right: 90px; /* change value to desired position */
             z-index: 1;
             /* the code below is only for this example */
             width: 35px;
             
             display: flex;
             align-items: center;
             justify-content: center;
             text-align: center;
         }

             .ebp_pdf:hover {
                 opacity: 0.9
             }


         .ebp_wrapper {
             float: left;
             width: 25%;
             align-items: center;
         }


         @media screen and (max-width: 985px) {


             [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
                 display: inline-block;
                 width: 100%;
             }




             .ebp_wrapper {
                 float: none;
                 margin: auto;
                 width: 60%;
             
                 
             }
         
        
         }
     </style>


    
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">

        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
             
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                    <a href="#" target=”_blank”><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                    <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>
             
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                <a href="#"><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                <a href="#"><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                <a href="#"><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    
</div>

  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now, I'm attempting to create a mobile responsive view with the images centered and below each other. When I try to center it, however, it puts it to the right rather than in the middle.

The Buttons in Desktop view:
[image]

The Buttons in Mobile View: As you can see it is far from the optional (The yellow rectangle)
[image]

**The question is, how could I center these images?**

***Edit**: My first attempt was with Bootstrap, but changing the screen size takes away the two buttons from each other.*

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the output

Comment: you are already using bootstarp, then why not take advantage of rows and columns in that. it will make your life easier

Comment: I added examples to the question. Bootstrap was my first attempt but it takes away the two buttons from each other if I change the screen size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<style>
           
    .tr {
         border: none;
     }

     .ebp_container {
         /* What you need */
         position: relative;
         /* the code below is only for this example */
         width: 300px;
         /*background-color: yellow;*/
         margin: 10px;
         padding: 20px;
     }

 


     .ebp_video {
         /* What you need */
         position: relative;
         z-index: 2;
         /* the code below is only for this example */
         width: 80px;
         /* height: 100px;*/
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         text-align: center;
         color: var(--eniac-blue);
         cursor: pointer;
         /*Background*/
         border-radius: 15px;



         /*Centering the immages*/
         display: block;
       margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
     }


         .ebp_video:hover {
             /*    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);*/
             opacity: 0.9
         }






     .ebp_pdf {
         /* What you need */
       
         position: absolute;
         top: 70px; /* change value to desired position */
         right: 90px; /* change value to desired position */
         z-index: 1;
         /* the code below is only for this example */
         width: 35px;
         
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         text-align: center;
     }

         .ebp_pdf:hover {
             opacity: 0.9
         }


     .ebp_wrapper {
         float: left;
         width: 25%;
         align-items: center;
     }


     @media screen and (max-width: 985px) {


         [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
             display: inline-block;
             width: 100%;
         }




         .ebp_wrapper {
                 width: 100%;
text-align: center;
         
             
         }
         
         .ebp_container {
margin: auto;
         }
     
    
     }
 </style>
```

Comment: add this style, it will resolve the issue

Comment: .ebp_wrapper {
                 width: 100%;
text-align: center;
         
             
         }
         
         .ebp_container {
margin: auto;
         }

this is what you have to replace

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have problem because of your `.ebp_container { width: 300px}`

If you change it to

```
.ebp_container {  width: 100%;  }
```

in your media query, it should work as you want

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
  </head>
  <body>

    <style>
               
        .tr {
             border: none;
         }

         .ebp_container {
             /* What you need */
             position: relative;
             /* the code below is only for this example */
             width: 300px;
             /*background-color: yellow;*/
             margin: 10px;
             padding: 20px;
         }

     


         .ebp_video {
             /* What you need */
             position: relative;
             z-index: 2;
             /* the code below is only for this example */
             width: 80px;
             /* height: 100px;*/
             display: flex;
             align-items: center;
             justify-content: center;
             text-align: center;
             color: var(--eniac-blue);
             cursor: pointer;
             /*Background*/
             border-radius: 15px;



             /*Centering the immages*/
             display: block;
           margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
         }


             .ebp_video:hover {
                 /*    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);*/
                 opacity: 0.9
             }






         .ebp_pdf {
             /* What you need */
           
             position: absolute;
             top: 70px; /* change value to desired position */
             right: 90px; /* change value to desired position */
             z-index: 1;
             /* the code below is only for this example */
             width: 35px;
             
             display: flex;
             align-items: center;
             justify-content: center;
             text-align: center;
         }

             .ebp_pdf:hover {
                 opacity: 0.9
             }


         .ebp_wrapper {
             float: left;
             width: 25%;
             align-items: center;
         }


         @media screen and (max-width: 985px) {


             [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
                 display: inline-block;
                 width: 100%;
             }




             .ebp_wrapper {
                 float: none;
                 margin: auto;
                 width: 60%;
             
                 
             }

             .ebp_container { 
                width: 100%; 
            }

         
        
         }
     </style>


    
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">

        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
             
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                    <a href="#" target=”_blank”><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                    <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>
             
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                <a href="#"><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                <a href="#"><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                <a href="#"><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    
</div>

  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your width when responsive is causing the overflow. Its set to a width greater than the viewport and is overflowing.

You also seem to have some position:absolute stuff which seems largely un-necessary for the positioning of your icons. I've reset that back to basics when it goes responsive, but I'd guess it isn't quite perfect on desktop from a code perspective.

I'd update your question by creating a code snippet that more accurately represents the visual problem experienced locally to make sure everyone can see exactly the problem. i.e. include your image references and colours.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
  </head>
  <body>

    <style>
               
        .tr {
             border: none;
         }

         .ebp_container {
             /* What you need */
             position: relative;
             /* the code below is only for this example */
             width: 300px;
             /*background-color: yellow;*/
             margin: 10px;
             padding: 20px;
         }

     


         .ebp_video {
             /* What you need */
             position: relative;
             z-index: 2;
             /* the code below is only for this example */
             width: 80px;
             /* height: 100px;*/
             display: flex;
             align-items: center;
             justify-content: center;
             text-align: center;
             color: var(--eniac-blue);
             cursor: pointer;
             /*Background*/
             border-radius: 15px;



             /*Centering the immages*/
             display: block;
           margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
         }


             .ebp_video:hover {
                 /*    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);*/
                 opacity: 0.9
             }






         .ebp_pdf {
             /* What you need */
           
             position: absolute;
             top: 70px; /* change value to desired position */
             right: 90px; /* change value to desired position */
             z-index: 1;
             /* the code below is only for this example */
             width: 35px;
             
             display: flex;
             align-items: center;
             justify-content: center;
             text-align: center;
         }

             .ebp_pdf:hover {
                 opacity: 0.9
             }


         .ebp_wrapper {
             float: left;
             width: 25%;
             align-items: center;
         }


         @media screen and (max-width: 985px) {

.ebp_container {
   width: auto;
   text-align: center;
}

.ebp_pdf,
 .ebp_video {
  position: static;
  display:inline-block;
 width: auto;
}

             [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
                 display: inline-block;
                 width: 100%;
             }




             .ebp_wrapper {
                 float: none;
                 margin: auto;
                 width: 60%;
             
                 
             }
         
        
         }
     </style>


    
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">

        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
             
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                    <a href="#" target=”_blank”><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                    <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>
             
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                <a href="#"><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                <a href="#"><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ebp_wrapper">

            <div class="ebp_container">
                <h5 style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="font-weight-bold">Some Text</h5>
                <a href="#"><div class="ebp_pdf far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" style="color: #b3001b"></div></a>
                <div><img class="ebp_video" src="eplay.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" /></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    
</div>

  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```